# Can anyone help me in finding the source (reference) for the following given verse.?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, puranas, ramayana, upapuranas

> ***ॐ तुभ्यं नमामि नारायणाय
> तुभ्यं नमामि जगदीश्वराय ।***
>
> ***हे लक्ष्मीकांतम तुभ्यं नमामि
> हे शांताकारम तुभ्यं नमामि ।।***

**Translation.:**

> ***"O Lord of the universe (Jagadishwaraya), I offer my respectful obeisances unto You, O Lord Nārāyaṇa.***
>
> ***O Lakshmikantam (Lord/Husband of Sri Lakshmi), I bow to You, O Shantakaram (One with the Peaceful Appearance), I bow to You."***

Can anyone please share from which Purana, Upa-Purana, etc., this verse dedicated to Narayan/Visnu is taken.?

I heard it is present in Ramananda Sagar's Ramayana Serial.

Comment: It seems perhaps from the Garuḍa Purāṇa, however I am not sure about it.